# C# ssl stream wont stop buffering before sending

Tags: c#, ssl

I am trying to use C# to connect over a ssl socket to a server and send xml data  back and forth.  It seems that data won't be sent till it has reached a certain packet size 1000 bytes, upon which all the packets are just smashed on top of each other.  Is there a way to force ssl library to send out packets as I send them?

I am using SslStream and StreamWriter to send the data, and i have already tried making packet size smaller and setting NoDelay to true to no avail.  Is there just something I am missing?

```
sslStream = new SslStream(sslClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback));
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(appSettings.CBPASServer);
showSslInfo(appSettings.CBPASServer, sslStream, true);
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream);
```

...

```
sslStream.Write(xml);
sslStream.Flush();
```

Comment: Another possibility just occurred to me: does the xml variable in your code represent a chunk of the xml you want to send, or the whole thing?

Comment: the whole thing, xml could be anything, also have just started sending the word buffalo with the same behavior

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was wondering how SSL/TLS could stream over a block cipher when it uses non streaming modes. This question sort of confirms my initial thought that it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's your StreamWriter that is chunking your data.  Try setting AutoFlush = true.

Comment: not a bad guess but I would think the immediate following flush i have would do the same thing.  Also I did try turning on autoflush with no luck.  Thanks for advice though